# unexpected behaviour when overwriting with +=

Tags: python

it stores the value in 'x' correctly sometimes. Is line `order_sum_inputs = order_sum_inputs/10` the culprit? I expect it to overwrite `order_sum_inputs = get_inputs()` when it comes out of the while loop, but I don't know if it is.

```
import random


my_inputs = []
for _ in range(1000):#random list of numbers
  my_list = random.randint(0, 1000)
  my_inputs.append(my_list)



def get_inputs():#sum two random numbers from the stored list
  input_1 = my_inputs[random.randint(0, 1000)]
  d = input_1
  input_2 = my_inputs[random.randint(0, 1000)]
  e = input_2
  sum_inputs = d + e
  return sum_inputs
  

def get_place_value():#store the order of magnitude
  
  x = 1
  order_sum_inputs = get_inputs()
  while order_sum_inputs >= 10:
    if order_sum_inputs/10 >= 10:
      x += 1
    order_sum_inputs = order_sum_inputs/10
  return x  

print(my_inputs)
print(get_inputs())
print(get_place_value())
```

Comment: Right now, this is just a chunk of code. We have no idea what it's *supposed* to do, and the variable names like `x` and `my_inputs` are not helping us discern the code's purpose. Explain, in words, what you expect this code to do and what it's currently doing, ideally with some concrete output for a given set of numbers.

Comment: It's storing the order of magnitude of the sum of two randomly generated numbers in the variable 'x'. its really  just an exercise at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You only set `order_sum_inputs` once outside the loop and then just replace it inside the loop. There is no overwrite since the `get_inputs()` is outside the loop

```
  order_sum_inputs = get_inputs() --<< do it once, not executed again
  while order_sum_inputs >= 10: --<< then enters the loop
    if order_sum_inputs/10 >= 10:
      x += 1
    order_sum_inputs = order_sum_inputs/10
```

Comment: i'm getting confused about precedence, i think. divisor being applied to the output of the defined function

Answer (score 0):

@robin

```
order_sum_inputs = get_inputs()
```

The code is not in the while loop, this means that it will keep on running until order_sum_inputs is greater than 10, which in this case is false.

```
  order_sum_inputs = get_inputs() #<-- Outside while loop
  while order_sum_inputs >= 10:
    if order_sum_inputs/10 >= 10:
      x += 1
    order_sum_inputs = order_sum_inputs/10
  return x
```

Here is the correct code:-

```
import random


my_inputs = []
for _ in range(1000):#random list of numbers
  my_list = random.randint(0, 1000)
  my_inputs.append(my_list)



def get_inputs():#sum two random numbers from the stored list
  input_1 = my_inputs[random.randint(0, 999)] #<-- 1000 index refers to 1001st number in python indexing which is out of range in your list, python indexing starts from 0 not 1
  d = input_1
  input_2 = my_inputs[random.randint(0, 999)]
  e = input_2
  sum_inputs = d + e
  return sum_inputs
  

def get_place_value():#store the order of magnitude
  
  x = 1
  order_sum_inputs = get_inputs()
  while order_sum_inputs >= 10:
    if order_sum_inputs/10 >= 10:
      x += 1
    order_sum_inputs = order_sum_inputs/10
    order_sum_inputs = get_inputs()
  return x  

print(my_inputs)
print(get_inputs())
print(get_place_value())
```